# Color operation in go

Tags: go, colors

There're some simple color operations, but the output is wrong. I'm just wondering what happened here.

main.c:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "image/color"
)

func main() {
    startColor := color.RGBA{0x34, 0xeb, 0x64, 0xff}
    endColor := color.RGBA{0x34, 0xc9, 0xeb, 0xff}
    fmt.Printf("%d-%d=%d\n", endColor.G, startColor.G, endColor.G-startColor.G)
}
```

output:

```
201-235=222
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`color.RGBA.G` is a `uint8`.](https://pkg.go.dev/image/color#RGBA)  Since 235 is bigger than 201, but uint8 doesn't store negative numbers like -34, the value is instead wrapping.

There's nothing `color` specific about the situation.
You [get the same answer](https://go.dev/play/p/9E1FZdFKZJo) (222) with:

```
    var g1, g2 uint8 = 0xc9, 0xeb
    fmt.Println(g1 - g2)
```

So nothing unusual, just standard [Go unsigned integer overflow wrapping](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Integer_overflow).  It isn't even undefined behavior.